# XSL default namespace with lookup file

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I have a input xml with a default namespace. eg as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="aaa">
<subroot>
    <country>aaa</country>
    <country>bbb</country>
    <country>ccc</country>
</subroot>
</root>
```

While transforming I use xpath-default-namespace="aaa" because otherwise xpaths will not match. Again I have to read a lookup xml using xsl key function. eg as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="aaa" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="LookupDoc" select="document('lookup.xml')" />
<xsl:key name="ObjectType-lookup" match="lookup" use="@att1" />

<xsl:template match="//country">
    <countrynew>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$LookupDoc/*">
            <xsl:with-param name="curr-code" select="string(.)" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </countrynew>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='lookups'>
    <xsl:param name="curr-code" />
    <xsl:value-of select="key( 'ObjectType-lookup' , normalize-space($curr-code))/@att2" />
</xsl:template>
```

with default namespace in stylesheet element xpath "//country" works fine. The problem arise when I read the lookup xml which doesn't have any namespace. eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x:lookups>
     <lookup att1="aaa" att2="zzz"/>
     <lookup att1="bbb" att2="yyy"/>
     <lookup att1="ccc" att2="xxx"/>
</x:lookups>
```

Is there any way that I can specify in template maching "lookups" to ignore xpath-default-namespace or to match any namespace including no namespce?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way that I can specify in template maching "lookups" to ignore xpath-default-namespace or to match any namespace including no namespce?

You can specify `xpath-default-namespace` anywhere in the stylesheet: an XPath expression will look up the tree and use the "nearest ancestor" value.

> For any element in the stylesheet, this attribute has an effective value, which is the value of the `[xsl:]xpath-default-namespace` on that element or on the innermost containing element that specifies such an attribute

([From the XSLT 2.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unprefixed-qnames))

So you could say

```
<xsl:template match='lookups' xpath-default-namespace=''>
```

to override the default namespace specified on the `xsl:stylesheet` element.  You can even specify it on a literal result element in the stylesheet, as `xsl:xpath-default-namespace`:

```
<something xsl:xpath-default-namespace="bbb" attr="{foo}" />
```

This would create a `<something attr="xxx" />` where `xxx` is the value of the `{bbb}foo` child element of the current context node.

Comment: I didn't knew xpath-default-namespace is usable in any place. For my actual situation I have number of xsl key functions. So what I did is move all key functions into a one document and put xpath-default-namespace="" to the stylesheet element. So I don't need to duplicate it in all key's. 

Thanks for the quick reply lan :)

Comment: @susithasenarath of course there's always the old-fashioned alternative of forgetting about `xpath-default-namespace` and instead mapping the URI to a prefix and using that in the XPaths, i.e. put `xmlns:a="aaa"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` and then use `<xsl:template match="a:country">`.

Comment: yes Lan I consider that too. But still will not look good in my situation because I have already done the xsl and it has hundreds of xpath expressions. So if I have to put a prefix on each of then it'll be a nightmare. xpath-default-namespace give me a easy way out put introduce this problem. Now every thing is fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did solve problem but sure there will be other ways. What I did was I move template match for lookup and key xsl function to a different document and in xsl stylesheed element I put xpath-default-namespace="". So for those xpath matching xsl use default namespace as none.

Still I'm curious weather there is a way to specify in template itself to use no namespace while matching.